# Print same code twice in two locations in one php file

Tags: php

I need two print the same rows which retrieved from the db, in two different locations in same php file. 
I know it is better to have a function. 
It tried, It doesn't work properly.
I am using the below code print the said rows/

```
 $get_g = "SELECT * FROM profile_groups";
 $get_gr = mysqli_query($condb ,$get_g);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($get_gr) > 0)
   {
      while($groups = mysqli_fetch_array($get_gr))
      {
         echo "<option value='".$groups['profile_gid']."'>".$groups['profile_gname']."</option>";
      }
   }
   else
   {
    echo '<option value="">Empty - No Groups!!</option>';
   }
```

I need to print exactly the same code twice in two different location in a php file.
I think it is not a good idea to retrieve data twice from the server by pasting the above code twice. 
Is there any way to recall or reprint the retrieved data in second place which I need to print.

**Edit** : Or else, if someone can help me to convert this to a function?
I converted this into a function. It prints only first row.

**Edit 2** : Following is my function

```
unction getGroup($dbconn)
{
 $get_g = "SELECT * FROM profile_groups";
    $get_gr = mysqli_query($dbconn ,$get_g);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($get_gr) > 0)
    {
        while($groups = mysqli_fetch_array($get_gr))
        {
            $groupData = "<option value='".$groups['profile_gid']."'>".$groups['profile_gname']."</option>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<option value="">Empty - No Groups!!</option>';
            }
return $groupData;
```

Comment: If you add your effort in converting it to a function, then perhaps we can help show you how to fix that.  This may be helpful to you in the future.

Comment: You do already have your data in your **$groups**  variable. So you do not need to request server again. You just display it using while or foreach .

Comment: @NigelRen - I added the function.

Comment: The function seems to half build up a string to pass back (but only the last part as you don't use `.=` to add the string on) and also echo out some of the content.  You should stick with one or the other.

Comment: @NigelRen - Which is better?

Comment: Functions would normally be better to not echo out things, just build the content and pass it back.  BUT better is always subjective.

Comment: @NigelRen - Can you help me to write the function correctly?

Comment: instead of closing the loop above you can loop through whole page and include that part also in the same page where you want to use the same loop data else you can create a array as mentioned by rakesh jankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the records coming from the DB in array and use a custom function to render the element

```
$get_g = "SELECT * FROM profile_groups";
$get_gr = mysqli_query($condb ,$get_g); 
$options = []; //store in an array
if(mysqli_num_rows($get_gr) > 0)
{
    while($groups = mysqli_fetch_array($get_gr))
    {
     $options[$groups['profile_gid']] = $groups['profile_gname'];
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `$options` array many times in your page

```
echo renderElement($options);

function renderElement($ops){
    $html = '';
    foreach($ops as $k => $v){
      $html .= "<option value={$k}>{$v}</option>";
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is same for both places, put the entire string into variable, then echo it on those two places.

instead of

```
echo "here\n";
echo "there\n";
```

do

```
$output = "here\n";
$output .= "there\n";
```

then somewhere

```
echo $output
```

on two places....

Comment: Its no problem. You can have a multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

Values are being stored in groups array, hence you can use a foreach loop elsewhere to get values from the array:

```
    $groups = array(); 
    $get_g = "SELECT * FROM profile_groups";
     $get_gr = mysqli_query($condb ,$get_g);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($get_gr) > 0)
       {
          while($groups = mysqli_fetch_array($get_gr))
          { 
             echo "<option value='".$groups['profile_gid']."'>".$groups['profile_gname']."</option>";
          }
       }
       else
       {
        echo '<option value="">Empty - No Groups!!</option>';
       }

    // use here
    foreach($groups as $group)
      {
         echo $group['profile_gid'] . " ". $group['profile_gname'] . "<br/>";  
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProfileGroups
{
    public $profile_groups_options;

    public static function get_profile_groups_options($condb) {
        $get_g = "SELECT * FROM profile_groups";

        if( isset( $this->profile_groups_options ) && $this->profile_groups_options != '') {
            return $this->profile_groups_options;
        }

        $get_gr = mysqli_query($condb ,$get_g);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($get_gr) > 0)
        {
            while($groups = mysqli_fetch_array($get_gr))
            {
                $this->profile_groups_options .= "<option value='".$groups['profile_gid']."'>".$groups['profile_gname']."</option>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->profile_groups_options .= '<option value="">Empty - No Groups!!</option>';
        }
        return $this->profile_groups_options;
    }

}

ProfileGroups::get_profile_groups_options($condb);
```

Comment: Using $this when not in object context. Also, you would need `$this->profile_groups_options .= ` instead of `$this->profile_groups_options = ` in your while loop.